# How to run a stored procedure as Siebel Server Job

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, siebel

Can I define a Server Job as Oracle Database Procedure?
I will need to schedule running a database procedure using Siebel Server Jobs.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that. If you are asking something like triggers that is a separate thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no Direct Method to run a DB stored procedure. The common way of implementing this is through the command line and calling SQL Plus. In [this tutorial](http://siebelmax.com/spharticle/read.asp?aid=6-9Y3JP045) it's explained in a step-by-step way. This will allow you to create a business service and use it in a workflow that can then be used to power a Siebel Job.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way on Unix servers:

1.Create a SQL script file on Siebel server(s) depending on your component definition on a particular server.

```
exec my_package.MY_STORED_PRC;
```

2.Call the file inside your BS:

```
Clib.system(“sqlplus $my_user/$my_password@dbname @//SBA_81/siebsrvr/bin/my_stored_proc_caller.sql”);
```

3.Define an RCR template, calling the BS/WF RunProcess:

4.Create RCR with scheduling time & start it.

---

You can also call the sql file inside a shell script file & invoke shell script file

Shell script file: my_shell_file.sh

```
sqlplus -S $my_username/$pwd@db_instance "@"my_stored_proc_caller.sql"
```

Give execute permission to the file.

Then execute it inside BS:

```
Clib.system(“/sieb/server/path/my_shell_file.sh")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this option by executing OOB BS "EAI ODBC Service" method "Execute Procedure". Hope it will help you

Comment: While answering try to elaborate as much as you can so that the answer gets conveyed properly. :) You can edit and add more details in your answer.